# Fix the inconsistent usage of the new checkmark color

Tags: feature-request, design

The accepted answer checkmark seems to have gotten mysteriously lighter. While I question why this change was even made in the first place, I have a bigger problem with this:

[image]

If you're going to change the color, please change both the check and the upvote text. My OCD can't handle it!

Comment: This isn’t the same request…

Comment: This is part of the rainbowificaiton project. First the colors of different elements with previously identically shades are varied slightly from one another. Over time the divergence will become more radical, and spread to more elements. Once the elements are all distributed evenly across the spectrum, the rainbowificaiton project. The focus group is split on stage two, disco feverification, where the colors are randomly assigned on pageload.

Comment: It seems as though questions get more pedantic all the time.